# Add images picked from image picker to recycler view, Android Studio, Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have been programming in Swift for 3 years and I am new to android development, I am trying to pick an image from image picker and put it into a recycler view, I can do this with hard coded images that are in my drawable folder but dont know how to do this with images I pick.

When I pick an image it is succesfull and i can show the image filepath

> I/System.out: Tony image path is /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/Max.jpg

When I try to add it to the array of already hard coded image names in the drawable folder it shows them images and a space at the end that is just blank

I presume it is because I am getting the hard coded images from the drawable folder and this picked image isnt in that folder maybe?

I dont want the hard coded images in the end product this was just to see the recycle view working.

I also am not saving them to the device they are being uploaded to a database after all feids are filled in the app, so they dontneed to ba added to the camera roll.

My Recycle View

```
class ArtistRecycleAdapter(val context: Context, val artists: List<ArtistImages>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArtistRecycleAdapter.ArtistHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArtistHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.images_added, parent, false)
    return  ArtistHolder(view)

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return artists.count()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArtistHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindProduct(artists[position], context)
}


inner class ArtistHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val artistImage = itemView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.artistImageMain)

    fun bindProduct(artists: ArtistImages, context: Context) {
        val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(artists.artistImage, "drawable", context.packageName)


        artistImage?.setImageResource(resourceId)

    }
}

}
```

My Activity result

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
        && null != data
    ) {
        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
            var count = data.clipData.itemCount
            for (i in 0..count - 1) {
                var imageUri: Uri = data.clipData.getItemAt(i).uri
                getPathFromURI(imageUri)
                println("Tony image uri is $imageUri")
            }
        } else if (data.getData() != null) {
            var imagePath: String = data.data.path
            Log.e("imagePath", imagePath)
            println("Tony image path is $imagePath")

            DataService.artistImages.add(ArtistImages(imagePath))
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see in your code is that you don't make a distinction between images from your resource folder and images you get from your intent request.

You can't use `setImageResource(resourceId)` to set the image if `resourceId` is the uri. `setImageResource` excepts an int which is the id of the resource.

Use `setImageURI(uri)` instead.

Edit, added this after discussion in the comments:

You can then remove the whole part with the resourceId and store the uri in your ArtistImage class and then access it like this:

```
fun bindProduct(artists: ArtistImages, context: Context) {
    artistImage?.setImageResource(artists.artistImage)

}
```

Comment: THank you for your time on this it makes sence, but how would I set my uri in the recycle view? if im replacing to 'artistImage?.setImageURI(uri)' what would i replace  'val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(artists.artistImage, "drawable", context.packageName)' with? as this is what is binding the resource

Comment: @TonyMerritt You can remove this whole line. You can save the path in a field in your `ArtistImages` class say in the variable `uri`. Then just access it with `artistImage?. setImageURI(artists.uri)`.

Comment: Exelent thank you for the time on this, it workes perfectly now.